# Is W3 Total cache compatible with Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, performance, contact-form-7, w3-total-cache

I just using w3 total cache plugin to speedup my website. It works great in many ways like page caching, db caching, object caching, js&css minification and also it reduces time taken for FBR(first byte request).

But when i checking pagespeed test in tools.pingdom.com, It shows some unwanted url(**www.mydomain.com/?_wpcf7_is_ajax_call=1&_wpcf7=63**) takes lot of time to complete the request which affects the performance.

After the deactivation of w3 cache plugin that unwanted url dissappeared. I know the cause of this issue - Because of the usage of contactform7 plugin with ajax call. But it needed w3 totalcache to eliminate caching contactform7

settings changed :

w3 pagecache tab-> advanced settings->never cache following pages:

1. /.*[].*
2. /?_wpcf7_is_ajax_call=1&_wpcf7=63/

but no use. Any help!!!

Answer (score 6):

W3TotalCache sets the "WP_Cache" constant to true, by adding this to wp-config.php:

```
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache
```

When WP_Cache is set to true, Contact Form 7 will make the Ajax call you describe.

This happens in script.js:

```
if (_wpcf7.cached)
  this.wpcf7OnloadRefill();
```

It seems that the functionality is really only needed, when you use captchas or quiz, as pointed out here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-wpcf7onloadrefill-not-useful-and-causing-load

To avoid the ajax call, you can place the following code in your functions.php:

```
// Hack Contact Form 7 to avoid unwanted ajax calls
// see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632244/is-w3-total-cache-compatible-with-contact-form-7
add_action('wpcf7_enqueue_scripts', 'hack_cf7');
function hack_cf7() {
    $_wpcf7 = array(
        'loaderUrl' => wpcf7_ajax_loader(),
        'sending' => __( 'Sending ...', 'contact-form-7' ) 
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'contact-form-7', '_wpcf7', $_wpcf7 );
}
```

Explanation:

Contact form 7 adds some inline javascript with wp_localize_script, which looks like this when WP_CACHE is set:

```
var _wpcf7 = {
    "loaderUrl":"http:\/\/elsassfonden.dk\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif",
    "sending":"Sender ...",
    "cached":"1"
};
```

When WP_CACHE is not set, it the "cached" property is leaved out.
This happens in the function wpcf7_enqueue_scripts() in controller.php

The code I supplied calls wp_localize_script just after wpcf7_enqueue_scripts() has been run. This in effect inserts the same inline code, but without the "cached" property, just below the inline code produced by contact form 7.

Enjoy!

Comment: this solution no longer works as wpcf7_ajax_loader() has been removed from the plugin

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the fix above by rosell.dk, but I got an error sayintg the function "wpcf7_ajax_loader()" was not found.

I guess the plugin changed structure recently, or some other reason.

Nevertheless, based on his solution, I made a slight change to check if it is the right handle, and then unset the "cached" key instead. This way any other keys in the array are kept.

```
class Filterable_Scripts extends WP_Scripts {
function localize( $handle, $object_name, $l10n ) {

    $l10n = apply_filters( 'script_l10n', $l10n, $handle, $object_name );
    if ('contact-form-7' === $handle) {
            unset($l10n['cached']); // This is where we remove the problem.
        }
        return parent::localize($handle, $object_name, $l10n);
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts'] = new Filterable_Scripts;
});
```

Just put in your functions.php file or in a site-specific plugin.

Comment: This was probably inspired by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108362/how-to-intercept-already-localized-scripts 

Which I also found when encountering this problem.
It is also valuable to note that if you are customizing this script to your needs... setting the $ln10['cached'] = 0 doesn't work. Somehow it interprets it as a string and the implicit to boolean typecast in javascript  makes it always true that way. Unsetting is the only option that works.

Downside to this approach is when the time comes you actually need this functionality again then you need to edit it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable these calls on the client side, e.g. in footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.wpcf7OnloadRefill=function(){};
</script>
```

This essentially blanks JS function that refills forms.

Answer (score 0):

**WP Super Cache** is known to conflict with Contact Form 7. It's often discussed in the [Contact Form 7 Support Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7) and mentioned elsewhere - see http://ocaoimh.ie/wp-super-cache/